# Request with client in phpUnit gives a different response than with cURL

Tags: curl, phpunit, symfony

My request with the client in phpUnit gives a different response than with cURL.

How this could be possible ?

```
    //Curl
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8888/web/app_dev.php/api/v1/users/16");  
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    dump($output);

    dump("--------");

    //phpUnit Client
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->request('GET', '/api/v1/users/16');
    $content = json_decode($client->getResponse()->getContent(), true);
    dump($content);
```

Responses:

```
{
    "id":16,
    "email":"gmail@gmail.com",
    "first_name":"Olivier",
    "last_name":"Peano",
    "sex":"Femme",
    "promotion":"Bac +1",
    "telephone":"0606060606",
}


"--------"

array:7 [
        "id"            => 16
        "first_name"    => "Lea"
        "last_name"     => "Peano"
        "sex"           => "Femme"
        "promotion"     => "Bac +1"
        "telephone"     => "0606060606"
]
```

Email appear with cUrl, not with the client.

Is that a different between these 2 methods ?

I use the Symfony3, FOSUserBundle and FOSRestBundle. But it doesn't matter because I send the same request.

Comment: are different symfony env: the cURL is calling the dev environment with the client of the testcase the synfony test environment so probably different database

Comment: No, this is executed on the same database (I have only one DB).

Comment: @Olivier Seems like you are creating the client with a base url which is different from `http://localhost:8888/web/app_dev.php/`, so you're probably getting data from a different server.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have fixed it. See answer bellow. Can I reward you with something, like best answer or something ?

Comment: @Olivier I'm afraid SO doesn't have that option, as well as 'convert comment to answer'. That's not a problem though ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BVengerov said:

> Seems like you are creating the client with a base url which is different from http://localhost:8888/web/app_dev.php/

I have fixed it with:

```
$client = static::createClient(array(), array('HTTP_HOST' => 'symfony.dev'));
$client->followRedirects(true);
```

Thank you.